# Set cookie not working after deleting previous cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I want to set a cookie if `Username` is entered and also want the previous cookie to get deleted. I am able to `unset` the previous cookie but new cookie is not working for me. It showing blank.

```
   if(!empty($User_Name))
   {
        unset($_COOKIE['username']);
        setcookie('username', $User_Name, time()+31536000);

        echo $_COOKIE['username']; // blank

   }
```

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is no need to unset the cookie. Because, when you set the cookie it will override the existing cookie ( if it exists ) or create a new one ( if it doesn't exist )

Comment: yes you are right. just straight forward use `setcookie`

Answer (score 0):

From the [**PHP Docs**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-notes)..

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires.

Comment: i am using ajax and i am using this part to refresh when username change.

Comment: See , you have just set the cookie `username` and you are instantly echoing it which **WILL** display the blank output ! That is what the linked documentation says.... when you do a refresh of the page and check an `echo $_COOKIE['username'];` , the thing will be visible.

Comment: but when i do refresh i got the same old username. and when i again login then i can see the new username. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Found that if the path is empty it applies only to the current path, if you specify "/" applies to all paths.

so    `/` did the trick.

```
setcookie('username', $User_Name, time() + (86400 * 7), "/");
```